# How does gravity affect different bodies?

Tags: gravity, visible-light

To my understanding,the force of gravity increases as the mass of the body increases (ex. the moon has less gravity than the earth). So, intuitively, I would come to assume that the force of gravity depends on the object's size. Neutrinos commonly pass through the entire earth in very large quantities. It seems gravity has little to no effect on them because their mass is so small. If this is true, why is mass-less light curved/bent into a black hole from its gravity when normally its path is not affected by gravity on earth (and shouldn't be 'cause they have no mass)?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [How is light affected by gravity?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34352/50583)

Comment: And many others.

Answer (score -2):

This can be understood in two ways -

1. Gravity acts on mass as well as energy. Light/photons are energy.
2. Black hole curves space (path of light) itself and light just follows that path.

Earth and black hole are not comparable in terms of strength of gravity.

Even if earth was very massive, you could not tell if path of light , or neutrino is bent or not, because all your measuring devices/mechanisms would bend accordingly, and everything would appear straight.

Comment: Funny how both our comments, very similar, have been down-voted, though it is unclear to me why.

Comment: No idea! May be how we worded it.