# Gravity Violation of conservation of energy?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, energy-conservation, potential-energy, mass-energy

If a satellite gains gravitational energy when shot into space but all matter becomes light, what happens to its potential gravitational energy? When matter turns into light, it loses mass, affecting gravitational energy. Would this violate the conservation of energy?

Comment: The lost in potential energy would probably be carried by the light and gravitational fields in the form of waves.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34352/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Matter becomes light?  Tell me more . . .