# What evidence suggests that light exerts a force of gravitational attraction?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, visible-light, photons, experimental-physics

I'm aware of other posts outlining the *theory* of how light generates a force of gravitational attraction, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22876/2451) Phys.SE post. I'm not so interested in this. I'm interested in what evidence exists for this phenomenon.

Is there any? Has it yet been possible to directly test, or observe, light giving rise to a force of gravitational attraction?

Comment: You could look into indirect tests of cosmology during the photon-dominated phase of universal expansion. Currently, the universe has low photon energy densities, and I'd be surprised if direct measurements existed for this effect...

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/113749/2451

Comment: gravitational lensing proves that light is effected by gravity. its not too big of a conceptual link from this to say light also produces its own gravity

Comment: Or that some characteristic of the gravitational field happens to affect light. There's no justification at all in such a leap of logic, and it seems there's no evidence at all to support this assertion.