# Why doesn't the decay mode of negative omega conserve rest mass?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, elementary-particles

There are 3 modes of decay via which a $$\Omega ^{-}$$ particle can decay

This is one of the decay:

$$\Omega ^{-} \rightarrow  \Xi ^{0} + \pi^{-}$$

Baryon number is conserved.
*Strangeness* number is not conserved so that would imply that the interaction involved is *weak*
Apparently, the rest mass isn't conserved either.

$$\Omega ^{-} = 1672\frac{\rm MeV}{c^{2}}$$
$$\Xi ^{0} = 1315\frac{\rm MeV}{c^{2}}$$
$$\pi^{-} = -140\frac{\rm MeV}{c^{2}}$$

Really, what does this mean? How is this a possible decay mode if the rest mass isn't conserved?

Comment: The mass deficit goes into the kinetic energy of the decay products

Comment: @JohnRennie
John, could you elaborate?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is (rest) mass conserved in special relativity?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/175444/is-rest-mass-conserved-in-special-relativity)

Comment: Hello, your question is perfectly sensible, but I think it's been asked and answered here before. I suggest you read the above the question and answers. For that reason, I'm suggesting that this question is closed.

Comment: @Physkid: in quantum field theory mass can change into (kinetic) energy and vice versa. That's how two 1GeV protons can produce a 125GeV Higgs boson in the LHC. In this case mass is being converted into kinetic energy. If you add up the total energy given by $E^2 = p^2c^2 + m^2c^4$ before and after you'll find it is constant.

Comment: Rest mass isn't conserved, best example I can think of this is $H\rightarrow \gamma\gamma$

Comment: @JohnRennie This makes sense. Good time to recall concepts on SR.
Also, for an particle A with rest mass, M, do we perform a negation on the rest mass such that the rest mass for the antiparticle of A has rest mass, -M?

Comment: No, in the standard model, all masses are positive.

Comment: @Omry Thank you. Helps to get subtleties and conventions out of the way.

Comment: Do you mean to have the $\pi^-$ with negative mass in your question? Rest masses are always positive.